# La conexión no se cerró. El estado actual de la conexión es abierta

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms, asincronismo, asynctask

Hola estoy realizando una inserción asíncrona de datos con el framework dapper en .NET,

El caso es que la primera vez si lo realiza, pero cuando muestro los datos, y lo realizo otra vez, este me indica el siguiente error.

> La conexión no se cerró. El estado actual de la conexión es abierta.

Esta es mi clase global donde realizo la conexión a la BD.

```
using System;


    namespace TendejonApp.DataAccess
    {
        public static class VariablesGlobales
        {
            private static System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection _GlobalConnection;


            public static System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection GlobalConnection
            {
                get
                {
                    _GlobalConnection = _GlobalConnection ?? new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString);
                    return _GlobalConnection;
                }

                set
                {
                    _GlobalConnection = value;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Y estoy implementando un DAO un capa de acceso a datos donde tengo mi método asíncrono

```
namespace TendejonApp.DataAccess
{
    public class RepositoryDA : DapperBase
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString);


       public async Task<UsuariosDTO> CrearUsuarioAsync( UsuariosDTO usuariosDTO ) {
            const string sql = @"[dbo].[spInsertUsuario]";

            var result = await VariablesGlobales.GlobalConnection.QueryAsync<UsuariosDTO>(sql, usuariosDTO, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            return result.FirstOrDefault();
        }


    }
}
```

Este es mi formulario donde llamo mi la funcion.

```
   private async void btnCrear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await VariablesGlobales.GlobalConnection.OpenAsync();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                //insertarUsuarios();

               InsertarUsuariosAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("Insertando..... " + i);
                pbEstado.Increment(i);
            }

        }


  async void InsertarUsuariosAsync() {
            UsuariosDTO usuario = new UsuariosDTO();
            usuario.Nombre = "Juan leonel";
            usuario.Apellido = "Albores";
            usuario.Email = "juan@correo.com";
            usuario.Password = "LEON1234";
            var result = await RepositoryDA.CrearUsuarioAsync(usuario);
        }
```

La primera vez, si realiza la inserción pero cuando muestro los datos en la aplicación y lo vuelvo a insertar, me indica el error de

> La conexión no se cerró. El estado actual de la conexión es abierta.

Alguien que me pueda orientar que estoy haciendo mal..

Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

es una mala práctica el usar "una conexión global" ya que puedes perder el contexto y no saber si se ha cerrado en un punto de tu ejecución del programa o en otro. La conexión se debe crear y destruir (o devolver al pool de conexiones) en el bloque más pequeño de código, o sea, en el método.
Te pongo un ejemplo de lo que quiero decir

```
public async Task<Clase> Get(int customerId)
{
    var parameters = new { customerId = customerId };
    using (Connection = CreateConnection(_connectionString)) // creamos la conexión en un bloque using para liberarla cuando termine la consulta
    {
        return await SpQueryFirstOrDefault(Querys.MiConsultaGet, parameters).ConfigureAwait(false); // ejecutamos una consulta de Stored Procedure y recuperamos el primer elemento
    }
}

public IDbConnection CreateConnection(string connectionString)
{
    Connection = new SqlConnection($"{connectionString}");
    return Connection;
}

protected async Task<T> SpQueryFirstOrDefault(string sql, object parameters)
{
    if (Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        Connection.Open();
    }
    return await Connection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<T>(sql, parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: mm tratare de adaptarlo